# Executing python script(having arguments) from shell script

Tags: python, linux, shell

**myfile.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "\n starting python script"
python main.py arg1
echo -e "\n done"
```

*This is not working.*

Above file has given following **error**

```
starting python script
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 97, in <module>
    main()
  File "main", line 80, in main
    header = "arg1: {}\n\n".format(sys.argv[1])
ValueError: zero length field name in format

done
```

**main.py**

```
...
...
def main():
    """ main function
    """

    header = "arg1: {}\n\n".format(sys.argv[1])
    ...
    ...


if __name__ == "__main__":

    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        main()
    else:
        print "\n Invalid no. of arguments"
        print "\n Usage:"
        print "\n python {} <date>\n".format(sys.argv[0])
        exit(1)
```

Whats the correct syntax to call a python script having arguments from shell script ?

Comment: Could you please be a little more precise? Maybe with a toy example?

Comment: Yes it is correct, what do you mean for *not working*? bash throws an error, python throws an error?

Comment: What is your Python version? Could we please get the python script?

Comment: @user189 updated question with main.py contents and my python version is 2.6.2

Comment: Seems to work with python2.7, don't have 2.6 unfortunately

Comment: Change {} --> {0}, or maybe upgrade to 2.7 if possible. So this is not problem of calling python, but a rather a problem of using the wrong syntax for the your python version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script should work fine.  Here is a toy sample:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "\n starting python script"
python main.py arg1 arg2 arg3
echo -e "\n done"
```

with main.py as

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import sys

print("In python pgm called from shell script with args:")
for i, a in enumerate(sys.argv):
    print("argument {0} is {1}".format(i, a))
```

The error is probably caused by the '{}'.  Need to have a recent enough python version for that to work (2.7 or better to be on the safe side...).  Otherwise specify the positional argument numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is correct. Try this for example:

#### main.py

```
import sys
print sys.argv[1]
```